# Use GetLastError() to retrieve custom exception properties

Tags: c#, exception, global-asax, getlasterror, application-error

So I've created a custom exception class (let's call it `CustomException`) along with some custom properties not found in the `Exception` class.  In the global.asax.cs file there is the `Application_Error` method that is called whenever an exception happens.  I'm using `Server.GetLastError()` to grab the exception that triggered the `Application_Error` method.  The problem is that `Server.GetLastError()` only grabs an `Exception` object and not the `CustomException` object that is being thrown along with its custom properties.  Basically the `CustomException` is stripped down to an `Exception` object when retrieved by `Server.GetLastError()`, thus losing the custom properties associated with `CustomException`.

Is there a way for `GetLastError()` to actually retrieve the `CustomException` object and not the stripped down `Exception` version?  This is needed in order to store the errors in a database table with more information than would normally be supplied by an `Exception`.

`Application_Error`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This var is Exception, would like it to be CustomException
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();           

    // Logging unhandled exceptions into the database
    SystemErrorController.Insert(ex);

    string message = ex.ToFormattedString(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

    TraceUtil.WriteError(message);
}
```

`CustomException`:

```
public abstract class CustomException : System.Exception
{        
    #region Lifecycle

    public CustomException ()
        : base("This is a custom Exception.")
    {
    }

    public CustomException (string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public CustomException (string message, Exception ex)
        : base(message, ex)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    // Would like to use these properties in the Insert method
    public string ExceptionCode { get; set; }
    public string SourceType { get; set; }
    public string SourceDetail { get; set; }
    public string SystemErrorId { get; set; }

    #endregion        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried verifying with the debugger what is the actual type of `ex` or perhaps its `InnerException` property?

Comment: It depends on `SystemErrorController.Insert(ex);`'s implementation, having your specific type here does not help when you pass it in to `Insert`, Also your exception really should have [a protected constructor that calls the base protected constructor and be marked as `Serializeable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the Server.GetLastError's result to CustomException:

```
var ex = Server.GetLastError() as CustomException;
```

Remember that in some situations your CustomException could not be the top exception in the StackTrace, in this case you'll need to navigate through the InnerExceptions to find the right one.

Please, check the @scott-chamberlain links about how to design custom exceptions.